# Centering a Modal for IE9 with a transparent background, why need position relative?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-9, less

The back story....
I'm creating a modal directive for AngularJS that should take any** content and display it centered in the page with a grey transparent background. Sounds like it should be simple. It was working fine until testing w/ IE9 which is the only browser we need to support.  Its an in-house site.  I have a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/brad8118/fHmFA/#base) working with it centered both vertically and horizontally, that probably could be cleaned up a little.  I'm assuming that its going to work, I'm on a mac right now.

The modal's html needs to be in the footer which is fixed to the bottom of the page. So

So I have two questions.

**1st-** When I was setting up the grey transparent background found that I needed so set the position as relative.  **Why is this needed?** [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/brad8118/fHmFA/#base)

```
.dialogbox-wrapper{
z-index:1000;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
/* When this isnt included this has the opacity */
position:relative;
```

}

**2nd-** We are using less and CSS3.  Is there a cleaner way?

Here's what I need - 
[image]

**Before anyone suggests !doctype HTML, its there.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As to #1**

For `z-index` to be honored, an element must have `position` of some kind. If `position: relative` is simply removed, then the default `static` position does not recognize the `z-index: 1000` and so the gray box's `z-index: 50` puts your "background" to the foreground.

**As to #2**

"Cleaner" can be so relative. Here is a [modified version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHmFA/7/) that centers it without the need for the `min-width` (which you expressed in your notations wanting to eliminate), by using `display: inline-block` with the container set to `text-align: center` (which is reset on the element itself). It also sets the `<a>` element for the "close" to `display: block` so that your `width: 200px` actually does something (an anchor is an inline element normally, which does not honor width). Of course, now `200px` for the `.row` is driving the width of the modal display.

It all works in IE9 for me.